# If or not working on null values

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code. The If contains an Or that when one of them (or both) is empty the code fails.

```
For Each cellName In sCMDB.Range("A2:A" & uCMDB)
    devName = cellName.Offset(, 1)
    devIP = cellName.Offset(, 10)
    modNum = cellName.Offset(, 7)
    modId = cellName.Offset(, 14)

Set mnScope = sScope.Range("A2:A" & uScope).Find(modNum, , , lookat:=xlWhole)
Set miScope = sScope.Range("B2:B" & uScope).Find(modId, , , lookat:=xlWhole)
    If (modNum = mnScope) Or (modId = miScope) Then
        sScope.Cells(mnScope.Row, 3).Copy sCMDB.Cells(cellName.Row, 19)
        sScope.Cells(mnScope.Row, 4).Copy sCMDB.Cells(cellName.Row, 21)
    Else
        sCMDB.Cells(cellName.Row, 19).Value = "Not Measured"
        sCMDB.Cells(cellName.Row, 21).Value = "Not Measured"
    End If
```

If nmScope or miSCope are null, the code doesn't go further.
I know I'm missing something, I just don't know what.

While any of the previous is not null, this is flawless, when at least one is empty is where the problem begins.

UPDATE1

After reviewing some comments, I figured out that the sScope.cell copied to the sCMDB.cells are being the problem here

```
Set mnScope = sScope.Range("A2:A" & uScope).Find(modNum, , , lookat:=xlWhole)
Set miScope = sScope.Range("B2:B" & uScope).Find(modId, , , lookat:=xlWhole)
    If ((modNum = mnScope) Or (modId = miScope)) Then
        **sScope.Cells(((miScope.Row) Or (mnScope.Row)), 3).Copy sCMDB.Cells(cellName.Row, 19)
        sScope.Cells(((miScope.Row) Or (mnScope.Row)), 4).Copy sCMDB.Cells(cellName.Row, 21)**
    Else
        sCMDB.Cells(cellName.Row, 19).Value = "N/A"
        sCMDB.Cells(cellName.Row, 21).Value = "N/A"
    End If
```

The issue is that if mnScope is nothing when checking the mnScope.row for getting the value that will be copy to sCMDB that value is empty.
I've tried to assign both rows to the same value in order to see if any of those can be retrieved.

Trying to avoid using multiple instances

```
If ((modNum = mnScope) Or (modId = miScope)) Then
    sScope.Cells(mnScope.Row, 3).Copy sCMDB.Cells(cellName.Row, 19)
    sScope.Cells(mnScope.Row, 4).Copy sCMDB.Cells(cellName.Row, 21)
    sScope.Cells(miScope.Row, 3).Copy sCMDB.Cells(cellName.Row, 19)
    sScope.Cells(miScope.Row, 4).Copy sCMDB.Cells(cellName.Row, 21)
```

Comment: Do you mean null as in a blank or zero-length string or null as in Nothing (no match to Find)? Are modNum and modId always non-blank? Are they supposed to be found on the same row in columns A & B?

Comment: null as in Nothing (no match to Find)

Comment: Column A and B got references values that modNum (A) and modId (B) needs to met. modNum and modId are not always blank, but tend to happen, sometimes is modNum, sometimes is modId, sometimes both, sometimes none. I'm trying to get them all at once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silly me, I was resolving the issue at the very beginning but not able to see it
Here I declare what I'm looking for

```
For Each cellName In sCMDB.Range("A1104:A1104")
    devName = cellName.Offset(, 1)
    devIP = cellName.Offset(, 10)
    modNum = cellName.Offset(, 7)
    modId = cellName.Offset(, 14)

The if is looking for it, and it was resolving on Nothing or else.
    If ((modNum = mnScope) Or (modId = miScope)) Then
        sScope.Cells(((miScope.Row) Or (mnScope.Row)), 3).Copy sCMDB.Cells(cellName.Row, 19)
        sScope.Cells(((miScope.Row) Or (mnScope.Row)), 4).Copy sCMDB.Cells(cellName.Row, 21)
    Else
        sCMDB.Cells(cellName.Row, 19).Value = "N/A"
        sCMDB.Cells(cellName.Row, 21).Value = "N/A"
    End If
```

But it was resolved early as we already looked for that value and found it (or not)

```
Set mnScope = sScope.Range("A2:A" & uScope).Find(modNum, , , lookat:=xlWhole)
Set miScope = sScope.Range("B2:B" & uScope).Find(modId, , , lookat:=xlWhole)
```

Thus mnScope is the result of the evaluation of "If modNum = mnScope or modId = miScope"

```
Set mnScope = sScope.Range("A2:A" & uScope).Find(modNum, , , lookat:=xlWhole)
Set miScope = sScope.Range("B2:B" & uScope).Find(modId, , , lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Not mnScope Is Nothing Then
        sScope.Cells(mnScope.Row, 3).Copy sCMDB.Cells(cellName.Row, 19)
        sScope.Cells(mnScope.Row, 4).Copy sCMDB.Cells(cellName.Row, 21)
    ElseIf Not miScope Is Nothing Then
        sScope.Cells(miScope.Row, 3).Copy sCMDB.Cells(cellName.Row, 19)
        sScope.Cells(miScope.Row, 4).Copy sCMDB.Cells(cellName.Row, 21)
    Else
        sCMDB.Cells(cellName.Row, 19).Value = "N/A"
        sCMDB.Cells(cellName.Row, 21).Value = "N/A"
    End If
```

Answer (score 1):

An null/empty Range object returns the VBA value *Nothing*. Therefore, try this instead:

```
For Each cellName In sCMDB.Range("A2:A" & uCMDB)
    devName = cellName.Offset(, 1)
    devIP = cellName.Offset(, 10)
    modNum = cellName.Offset(, 7)
    modId = cellName.Offset(, 14)

Set mnScope = sScope.Range("A2:A" & uScope).Find(modNum, , , lookat:=xlWhole)
Set miScope = sScope.Range("B2:B" & uScope).Find(modId, , , lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Not (mnScope Is Nothing Or miScope Is Nothing) Then
        If (modNum = mnScope) Or (modId = miScope) Then
            sScope.Cells(mnScope.Row, 3).Copy sCMDB.Cells(cellName.Row, 19)
            sScope.Cells(mnScope.Row, 4).Copy sCMDB.Cells(cellName.Row, 21)
        Else
            sCMDB.Cells(cellName.Row, 19).Value = "Not Measured"
            sCMDB.Cells(cellName.Row, 21).Value = "Not Measured"
        End If
    End If
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried yours but after "If Not (mnScope Is Nothing Or miScope Is Nothing) Then" the code ends.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a check for both the `nmScope` and `nmScope` to ensure that they do not equal `vbNullString`.

```
For Each cellName In sCMDB.Range("A2:A" & uCMDB)
    devName = cellName.Offset(, 1)
    devIP = cellName.Offset(, 10)
    modNum = cellName.Offset(, 7)
    modId = cellName.Offset(, 14)

Set mnScope = sScope.Range("A2:A" & uScope).Find(modNum, , , lookat:=xlWhole)
Set miSCope = sScope.Range("B2:B" & uScope).Find(modId, , , lookat:=xlWhole)
    If ((modNum = mnScope) Or (modId = miSCope)) And _
            miSCope <> vbNullString And nmScope <> vbNullString Then
        sScope.Cells(mnScope.Row, 3).Copy sCMDB.Cells(cellName.Row, 19)
        sScope.Cells(mnScope.Row, 4).Copy sCMDB.Cells(cellName.Row, 21)
    Else
        sCMDB.Cells(cellName.Row, 19).Value = "Not Measured"
        sCMDB.Cells(cellName.Row, 21).Value = "Not Measured"
    End If
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. This one helped me out. I've edited the original post to reflect the current issue